# LDAPError while authenticating aprasad: INAPPROPRIATE_AUTH

Tags: openldap

My env.

AWX( Ansible Tower)  on Centos 7 with docker.
And I'm trying to connect AWX with LDAP.
It's finding the user but not able aloowing it to authenticate.

I was able to run ldapsearch command and it gave to the expected result. But its not accepting the p/w with AWX webgui.

{"log":"2020-09-25 23:15:59,824 DEBUG    django_auth_ldap search_s('cn=accounts,dc=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX', 2, '(cn=%(user)s)') returned 1 objects: cn=aprasad,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-09-25T23:15:59.82497491Z"}
{"log":"2020-09-25 23:15:59,828 WARNING  django_auth_ldap Caught LDAPError while authenticating aprasad: INAPPROPRIATE_AUTH({'msgtype': 97, 'msgid': 3, 'result': 48, 'desc': 'Inappropriate authentication', 'ctrls': []},)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-09-25T23:15:59.828941005Z"}

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue .

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue . I was referring the AWX/Ansible document . I guess it's wrong. Once I added these entries "uid=%(user)s,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX" in the :LDAP USER DN TEMPLATE" it started working . In the document and many blogs I read , either they tell you to keep this blank for put entries like (uid=%(user)s) .